# How would I configure my .htaccess to this specification?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I've looked around the internet for a comprehensive .htaccess guide to no avail so I was wondering if one of the users on this site could help me configuring it to what I need done with an explanation so I can, in future, sort it out myself.

What I need done is

```
http://www.url.com/view/{id}
```

to actually be

```
http://www.url.com/home.php?p=10&id={id}
```

If you could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to learn about Apache Mod_Rewrite Module. `.htaccess` is only general purpose directory access behavior configuration file for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the following in an .htaccess file in the root web directory will provide the specification you have outlined.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # (optional) do not rewrite if the request points to an actual file or directory on disk
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # rewrite the request
  RewriteRule ^view/(.*) /home.php?p=10&id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Great reference here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy and configure Mod_Rewrite module to work with your Apache server. Then, add following lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/(.+) /home.php?p=10&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the initial slash, but this works. Is `(.+)` the way a variable is declared in `.htaccess`?

Comment: (.+) is a match pattern. '.' matches "any character", and '+' is saying "1 or more". in my answer I used '*' which says "0 or more" (I wasn't sure given your question whether or not that was a possibility). at the end of the rule the [L] indicates this is the last redirection rule and so there is not further redirect processing when a URI matches this rule.

Comment: `(.+)` is a construction used in Regular Expresions, which in turn are leveraged by mod_rewrite module. If you want to know mod_rewrite or usage of `.htaccess`, you should at first go through tutorial about Regular Expressions.